# How to create XML file on server using stored procedure or cursor 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my database (`GoogleSEOData`), I have got one Table (GoogleMarkupList) and below sample data are there in table:

```
PUBLICATION_ID  |   PAGEID  |   URL
-------------------------------------------------------------
233             |   654345  |   /english/index.aspx
345             |   654345  |   /de/english/index.aspx
432             |   654345  |   /ru/russian/index.aspx
533             |   654345  |   /ae/arabic/index.aspx
233             |   452323  |   /english/offers.aspx
345             |   452323  |   /de/english/offers.aspx
432             |   452323  |   /ru/russian/offers.aspx
533             |   452323  |   /ae/arabic/offers.aspx
233             |   834343  |   /english/destinations.aspx
345             |   834343  |   /de/english/destinations.aspx
432             |   834343  |   /ru/russian/destinations.aspx
533             |   834343  |   /ae/arabic/destinations.aspx
```

Now I want to write SQL Procedure which will take File Path of the server as input say (D://GoogleMarkup) and would create below type of XML files on server (For above sample data).

Name of XML file for 654345 type of data will be `654345.XML`

```
<ps>
<p n="233" u="/english/index.aspx" />
<p n="345" u="/de/english/index.aspx" />
<p n="432" u="/ru/russian/index.aspx" />
<p n="533" u="/ae/arabic/index.aspx" />
</ps>
```

Name of XML file for 452323 type of data will be `452323.XML`

```
<ps>
<p n="233" u="/english/offers.aspx" />
<p n="345" u="/de/english/offers.aspx" />
<p n="432" u="/ru/russian/offers.aspx" />
<p n="533" u="/ae/arabic/offers.aspx" />
</ps>
```

Name of XML file for 834343 type of data will be `834343.XML`

```
<ps>
<p n="233" u="/english/destinations.aspx" />
<p n="345" u="/de/english/destinations.aspx" />
<p n="432" u="/ru/russian/destinations.aspx" />
<p n="533" u="/ae/arabic/destinations.aspx" />
</ps>
```

I know there is utility

```
SQLCMD -S Server -d Database -E -v pageid=%pid% 
       -Q "Select publication_id as [n], url  from table as [p] where pageid=$(pageid) for xml auto, root('ps')" 
       -o D://GoogleMarkup/%pid%.xml
```

But how to create all the XMLs in one go, so that it will read pageid one by one and would pass to `SQLCMD` to create XML, do I need to write cursor for that, please suggest with some good code sample.

Please suggest!!

Comment: SQLCMD can only create one file at a time.  Consider writing a C# application instead.

Comment: @Andomar But we can loop to pass Pageid to it an it will create xml according...how we can use this in SQL only. if it can't be done in SQL only what will be approach for creating C# application...Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a SP to cycle and repeat the command to create the XML file

**IMPORTANT:**
The sqlcmd utility requiers **:XML ON sqlcmd command on the single line**!

Without `:XML ON` sqlcmd command the result is like:

```
XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
---------------------------------------------------
0x440249004400440546006C006F00610074004408440061007...

(1 rows affected)
```

**This is a reason why we can't use the inline sql query to export data to xml using sqlcmd.**

But we can use the `bcp` utility for inline sql queries.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DO_XML]
AS 

Declare @PAGEID int
, @PAGEID_TEXT varchar(100)
, @CMD varchar(2000)
, @FILE varchar(100)

-- local cursor to cycle
DECLARE cXML CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT  PAGEID from GoogleMarkupList with (NOLOCK) group by PAGEID  

OPEN cXML

    FETCH NEXT FROM cXML INTO @PAGEID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN
        set @PAGEID_TEXT = cast(@PAGEID as varchar(100))

        -- dynamic command to create XML
        -- MUST BE ALL IN 1 LINE
        set @CMD = 'bcp "Select publication_id as [n], url  from GoogleSEOData.dbo.GoogleMarkupList as [p] where pageid='+ @PAGEID_TEXT +' FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT(''ps'')"  queryout E:\GoogleMarkup\'+@PAGEID_TEXT+'.XML -S MANOJ-PC\KRISH -T -c'

        -- do it
        exec master..xp_cmdshell @CMD, no_output

        FETCH NEXT FROM cXML INTO @PAGEID

END    
CLOSE cXML
DEALLOCATE cXML
```

This SP has been tested and work correctly by creating all the XML files

**Add what about the command line ?**

here the example:

```
bcp "Select publication_id as [n], url  from GoogleSEOData.dbo.GoogleMarkupList as [p] where pageid=452323 FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('ps')" queryout E:\GoogleMarkup\452323.xml -S GoogleSEOData -T -c
```

For more info:
[SQL Server Export using bcp/sqlcmd Utilities and XML](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-xml.htm)

Hope it help

Comment: @Luke...many thanks so I just need to execute the proc, anything which I have to take care while running above procedure so that it does not break...is SQLCMD will run from there and what I need to put in -S Server -d Database -E  as this would run on sql query only.

Comment: Interesting approach, though I wouldn't recommend xp_cmdshell in production if you can avoid it. +1

Comment: @Andomar yep correct but i follow the question to provide that way

Comment: @M.S i added more info about how to use the option as -S -d -E

Comment: I am getting this a results Running [dbo].[DO_XML].

No rows affected.
(0 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = 0
Finished running [dbo].[DO_XML].

Comment: I changed my SQLCMD command and while running the proc, I got this string SQLCMD -S "MANOJ-PC\KRISH" -d "master.dbo" -E -v pageid=345343 
       -Q "Select publicationid as [n], url as [u] from GoogleMarkupList as [p] where pageid=$(345343) 
        for xml auto, root('ps')" 
       -o E://GoogleMarkup/345343.XML

Comment: When u got 0 rows affcted did u check if you have the XML files on the folder ? And then if you change the SQLCMD the -d must be GoogleSEOData [db name] (check the sintax in the link provided) http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms162773(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: No I didn't got any xml in my E://GoogleMarkup/ foler and Just for testing at my local environment I used SQLCMD -S MANOJ-PC\KRISH -d master -E, how can I test whether above command is working fine for me as when I run separately Select publicationid as [n], url as [u] from GoogleMarkupList as [p] where pageid=345343 for xml auto, root('ps') it works for me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11776/discussion-between-m-s-and-luka)